# Loading request into web view from another view

Tags: ios, objective-c

In a part of my iPhone (iOS 5/6) app, I have a series of buttons that open a URL (currently through a URL scheme to mobile Safari) WITHIN MY APP. I do not wish to make separate view controllers which each act as modal at each button push.

Rather than having 5 unnecessary view controllers, I would like to make a .xib file that acts as an application-wide web view. IE: when a user presses a button, the URL corresponding to that button opens in this new view (let's say it's called WebViewController).

With pseudo code or just an explanation, could you please explain how I should going about doing this? There is very little online/in books for this specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a single view controller that will have a UIWebView outlet attached to it. Create a method that initializes that view controller with a URL parameter and load it into the UIWebView. Is that it?

Some pseudocode as well, since you requested it:

```
// SomeControllerWithinTheApp.m
- (IBAction)myWebsiteLinkTapped {
  MyWebController *viewController = [[MyWebController alloc] initWithURL:kWebsiteURL];
  // show it modally or push, up to you
}

// SomeOtherControllerWithinTheApp.m
- (IBAction)someLinkButtonTapped {
  MyWebController *viewController = [[MyWebController alloc] initWithURL:kSomeOtherURL];
  // show it
}
```

On the `-viewDidLoad` method of `MyWebController` load the `URLRequest` created with the passed url and load it into your web view.

Comment: There's a problem: '[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "WebViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

Comment: Here's my code: 
WebViewController.m:
`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:urlToLoad]];
}
- (id)initWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

    [self setUrlToLoad:url];
    return self;
}`

FifthViewController.m:
`- (IBAction)pushedArts:(id)sender {
    WebViewController *wvc = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.a.com"]];
    [self presentModalViewController:wvc animated:YES];`
}

I have an xib (WebViewController) with all outlets connected (the view included). What are you thoughts? Thank you

Comment: In WebViewController.h, I declare my webView: `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;`

Answer (score 1):

You could have basically one `viewController` and multiple buttons and then connect those buttons with their actions for opening the corresponding `URL`, You can use other `viewController` with `UIWebView` connected as iboutlet and a `UIButton` to dismiss this viewController you will have to implement the [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for the webview in this second viewController

**FirstViewController.m**

```
-(IBAction)button1Clicked:(id)sender{
    self.myWebController=[[MyWebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyWebViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.myWebController setWebViewUL:@"http://www.google.com"];

    [self presentViewController:self.myWebController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(IBAction)button2Clicked:(id)sender{
    self.myWebController=[[MyWebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyWebViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.myWebController setWebViewUL:@"http://www.apple.com"];

    [self presentViewController:self.myWebController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
-(IBAction)button3Clicked:(id)sender{
    self.myWebController=[[MyWebViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyWebViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.myWebController setWebViewUL:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];

    [self presentViewController:self.myWebController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**MyWebViewController.m**

```
@synthesize myWebView;
@synthesize strURL;


-(void)setWebViewUL:(NSString*)urlstr{

    self.strURL=urlstr;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self loadURLinWebView:self.strURL];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

-(void)loadURLinWebView:(NSString*)urlStr {

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:30.0f];
    [myWebView loadRequest:request];

}

-(IBAction)buttonDismisClicked:(id)sender{


    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}


// delegate methods     

-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error{

}
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

}

-(void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{


}
```